# I am getting a permission error even though I allowed permissions, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10282 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

This is my manifest file:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.user.appidea">


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
```

This is the code for my button so when pressed it sends a text message:

```
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String messageToSend = "this is a text";
                    String number = "XXXX";

                    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null,null);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions.